# Stopping recursion in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

```
connect(raj,isa,indian).
connect(indian,isa,man).

attribute(raj,marks,100).
attribute(indian,marks,200).

p(Node,marks,Number) :- 
   attribute(Node,marks,Number).
p(Node,marks,Number) :-
   connect(Node,isa,X),
   p(X,marks,Number).
```

So now, while querying,

```
171 ?- p(raj,marks,100).
true .

172 ?- p(raj,marks,200).
true .
```

In this case, I want `p(raj,marks,200)` to fail.

How do I stop recursion while getting the first answer?

Comment: Both of those queries run nicely to completion. Did you post the wrong query?

Comment: Raj's marks should be 100 and should throw false for 200. How do I stop recursing when I get 100?

Comment: But prolog doesn't "throw false". And it stops when it gets the first answer. Your program is valid for `p(raj,marks,200).` - the facts `connect(raj,isa,indian),  and `attribute(indian,marks,200)` make the rule work.

Comment: IMO @Enigmativity is right. What's the problem?!

Comment: See, I've editted the question.

Comment: @Rahul so you want `p(raj, marks, 200)` to be false because there's another solution that occurs before it? That would be odd behavior. Why would this be needed? It should be true if it satisfies the rule. If it needs to fail the rule, the rule semantics need to change (it's not clear what the meaning of your rule is). If you want to prune the solution to the first one, then my answer is what achieves that.

Comment: Can you explain why you want `p(raj, marks, 200)` to fail? What is the meaning of your predicate?

Comment: All Indians have marks = 200. So any guy who is indian will have marks=200; any Rahul, Albert who is an Indian will have marks = 200.
But, Raj (who is also an Indian) has a specific property that his marks is 100. 
So, Raj marks = 200 should fail.

Comment: That needs to be described as logic rather than just an example. Would it be correct to say that if the marks are obtained by virtue of the `attribute`, then you wouldn't want any "indirect" marks as a result of the `connect`? If that's the case, then the the cut I showed in my answer would be a working approach, and you would indeed want `p(raj, marks, X)` to *only* yield 100 as the answer shows. If that's not the right logic, then more explanation is needed.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you're wanting Prolog not to prompt for more solutions after confirming these examples are `true`? You could *potentially* do this with a cut, since the cut prunes the backtracking at a certain point:

```
p(Node, marks, Number) :- 
   attribute(Node, marks, Number),
   !.                       % Don't backtrack after confirming the attribute
p(Node, marks, Number) :-
   connect(Node, isa, X),
   p(X, marks, Number).
```

Now your queries as stated will not backtrack, as I think you're asking, after confirming the solutions:

```
| ?- p(raj, marks, 100).

yes
| ?- p(raj, marks, 200).

(1 ms) yes
| ?-
```

**But this presents a problem. Your predicate will no longer find all valid solutions to the query, `p(raj, marks, X)`.** It will stop after finding only one, even though there are more.

```
| ?- p(raj, marks, X).

X = 100

yes
| ?-
```

If we take the cut back out of the code (going back to your original code), it gives the correct response with all of the valid solutions for `X`:

```
| ?- p(raj, marks, X).

X = 100 ? ;

X = 200 ? ;

no
| ?-
```

**Another option to get the result you're after** is to use the `once/1` predicate, which will only seek the first solution and then stop backtracking:

```
| ?- once(p(raj,marks,100)).

(1 ms) yes
| ?-
```

Now, we haven't broken the `p/3` query and have a way to get the first solution without a backtrack. You could build a separate predicate around this if you wish:

```
p_once(Node, Marks, Number) :- once(p(Node, Marks, Number)).
```

And then, of course:

```
| ?- p_once(raj,marks,100).

(1 ms) yes
| ?-
```

But using `once/1` explicitly is preferred, in my opinion, since it is concise and makes the intention clear, while preserving the integrity of your original predicate.

Comment: Why not take the high road? The problem is IMHO on a different level (modeling, representation). `(!)/0` *has* its uses, but encourages beginners to adapt a "bad coding + quick fixing" style right from the start, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @repeat on the contrary, I'm not encouraging use of cut here. I was explaining why it's not a good idea. I believe my answer is saying exactly the point your comment is making (see starting with *But this presents a problem*)! Why the downvote?

Comment: Ok, good point. I just checked my voting record and my reputation info; according to both I haven't downvoted *anything* today.

Comment: @repeat ok, thanks. It was just a simultaneous event. Sorry. Not sure who or why I got the downvote from then. Not sure I care. I'll probably just delete the answer.

Comment: No harm done! A bit of highlighting sure can help.  I'm not 100% sure about the ground rules for Prolog answers here on SO, but I personally would favor splitting some 2/3/4-in-1 answers into 2/3/4 separate answers to avoid mixed messages.

Comment: Do not delete, multiply! Make each self-contained with its pros and cons, with a clear, simple message.

Comment: @repeat I don't think my answer has mixed messages if whoever is reading it cares to read the whole thing. I thought it was pretty straightforward. I often post an answer on SO if I see a viewpoint not being expressed completely in an answer or a comment. There are certainly way smarter Prologers (you being one of them) than myself here and can see things immediately that I don't always see. I'm also not often afforded the time to elaborate more on the answer at the time I post it, but sometimes later on. Overall, I don't find SO generally an "inviting" place to offer helpful information.

Comment: Rest assured that I value your contributions, your opinions, and your point of view. The way I see it, community is more than the sum of its parts. It is the relation that matters. If you have ideas in how we can make it more inviting, I'm all ears...

Comment: @repeat no worries. Those are just general feelings of SO melancholy I get occasionally. :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the solution. Basically, I could have been more specific with the question but I didn't think of different interpretations.

I want p(raj,marks,200) to return false.

Comment: @Rahul - Just to be picky - prolog doesn't return anything, so `p(raj,marks,200)` can't return `false`. It can either succeed or fail to be true, but it doesn't return `true`, `false` or anything.

Comment: I mean I want it to fail.